# How can i implement a voting plugin in index page of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using a voting plugin that only displays in single post page using the code below. However, i want to implement the same in the index.php page

```
        if ( is_singular(explode(',',$type))) // Replace is_singular with is_home;
        {    
            $voting_themes = get_option( 'voting_themes' ); 
            $voting_display = '';
            $voting_display .= $content; 
            $voting_display .= '<div class="voting-container">';
            
            if($voting_themes== "flat")
                {
                    $voting_display.= voting_themes_flat(get_the_ID());
                }
          
            $voting_display .='</div>'; 
            return $voting_display;
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel. You need support for a short-code, what plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi @rock3t. the plugin is called Voting by paratheme

Comment: Hi @Daniel. I looked at the plugin, sadly it does not have documentation I could glance over. We can do a custom solution. When you say you want to implement **in the index.php page**, what do you mean?

Comment: @rock3t it only works in the single post template. However, i want to use it the homepage as well where i have posts listed.